# Spring cloud gateway returns empty response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am trying to use Spring Cloud Gateway for routing my microservice, but even if the microservice is working expectedly gateway routing returns an empty response.
My microservice is a simple application and it's running on port `5861`. I routed my Gateway to it simply by predicting all cases to be sure it routed, after my routing trials with specific paths.

That's my Gateway configuration file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: product_service
          uri: localhost:5861/
          predicates:
            - Path=/product-service/**
```

After running both service and hitting them, my microservice returns response properly:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:5861/product/

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5861...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5861 (#0)
> GET /product/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5861
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2022 19:41:40 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":1,"name":"Apple","price":2},{"id":2,"name":"Apple","price":2},{"id":3,"name":"Apple","price":2}]
```

But if I try to do this from my API gateway it returns nothing, if I try to reach it from my browser a blank page occurs.

```
$ curl -v  http://localhost:5860/product-service/product

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5860...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5860 (#0)
> GET /product-service/product HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5860
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Can someone help me with what I am missing? I want to get the same response from the gateway.

**Edit:**

Working update:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: product_service
          uri: http://localhost:5861/
          predicates:
            - Path=/product
```

Comment: Does localhost:5861/product-service/product work?

Comment: @spencergibb no ı am trying to route the gateway to my service if the gateway endpoint starts with "/product-service", What else I can do instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your application has `/product/` endpoint exposed.
From gateway, you are trying to redirect from `/product-service/product` to `/product/` of service.
By default, spring cloud gateway redirects to Uris as they are. So currently, I believe that `http://localhost:5860/product-service/product` is being redirected to `http://localhost:5861/product-service/product`.

If you need to redirect from `product-service/**` to `/**` of product-service then use `RewritePath` filter.

here is an example usage that may work for you:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: product_service
          uri: localhost:5861/
          predicates:
            - Path=/product-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/product-service/(?<segment>/?.*),$\{segment}
```

Comment: SetPath and StripPrefix would also work https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#gatewayfilter-factories

Comment: But why does it return an empty message, it must return Whitelabel error or 404 not found because of an incorrect endpoint, in this scenario. If I try to use that changing " predicates: - Path=/product/** " and " uri: localhost:5861/ " it still returns the same empty messsage.